# row reduced form with element $i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

find rank(A)

find basis of$ R(L_A)$ consisting of column vectors

find basis of $N(L_A)$
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&i&-1\\1+i&1&1+2i\\1-i&2&1+i\\-i&1-i&1\end{array}\right]$$
i figure out the reduce form is 
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&1\\0&1&i\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$, so the rank(A)=2, but what is basis of $R(L_A)$ and$N(L_A)$

Comment: If you reduced right, the same method for getting bases for row space and null space as usual works, since complexes are a field.

Comment: How would you find these bases if you had a $2$ there instead of $i$? Do the same thing.

Comment: for nullspace i got x1=x3  x2=-ix3 x3=x3 so i got basic of N(A)=1 -i 1

Comment: for range(A)i find the row of of pivot row which are first and sec row

Answer (score 0):

basic of A is $$N(A)=\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\i\\1\\\end{array}\right]$$
 and basis of R(A) is $$R(A)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&i\\1+i&1\\1-i&2\\-i&1-i\end{array}\right]$$, am i doing right